# How to resize high quality image from gallery to appear in image view?

Tags: android, kotlin, gallery

in my app when i open gallery and pic an image it appears but when this image is high quality the image view show nothing  also in another phone the image from camera appear horizontally by it self

```
class Horizontal : Fragment() , EasyPermissions.PermissionCallbacks{

    private var currentImage: Bitmap? = null
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? { val view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.horizontal, container, false)

        val btng = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.btn_gallery_Hz) as FloatingActionButton

        btng.setOnClickListener {openGallary()
            selectImageInAlbum()}
        btng.scaleType = ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER
        return view}

    private fun selectImageInAlbum() {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
        intent.type = "image/*"
        if (intent.resolveActivity(activity!!.packageManager) != null) {
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1} }




    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop();if (currentImage != null)
        {currentImage!!.recycle();currentImage = null;System.gc()}}



    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode==2&&resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            val selectedImages = data.data
            val filePathColon = arrayOf(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)
            val cursr = this.activity?.contentResolver?.query(selectedImages!!,
                filePathColon, null, null, null)
            cursr!!.moveToFirst()
            val columnindex = cursr.getColumnIndex(filePathColon[0])
            val picturepath = cursr.getString(columnindex)
            cursr.close()
            val intent = Intent(activity, ResHzL::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("asd", picturepath)
            startActivity(intent)}}




    @AfterPermissionGranted(2)
    private fun openGallary() {
        val perms = arrayOf(
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
        if (EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(this.activity!!, *perms)) {

            // Toast.makeText(activity, "Opening gallary", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
        } else {EasyPermissions.requestPermissions(this,
            getString(R.string.weneedper), 2, *perms) }}
    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<String>, grantResults: IntArray
    ) { super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        EasyPermissions.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults, this)}
    override fun onPermissionsDenied(requestCode: Int, perms: MutableList<String>) {
        if (EasyPermissions.somePermissionPermanentlyDenied(this, perms)) {
            AppSettingsDialog.Builder(this).build().show()}}
    override fun onPermissionsGranted(requestCode: Int, perms: MutableList<String>) {}}
```

And in the other activity i use this to show the image

```
val imageView = findViewById<View>(R.id.mainImg_Hz) as ImageView
        imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(intent.getStringExtra("asd")))
```

Can any one could help ?

Comment: follow https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap.html

Comment: For image loading you can use _Glide_ or _Picasso_. If you don't want to use it then you have to manually resize your image as per scale and aspect ratio.

Comment: Lot of this things can be done by using a external library like Picasso or Glide. There are lot of things that you need to take care of when working with images, especially like resizing scaling and optimally using the devices memory and cleaning up resources. So its a no brainier for me to use one of those popular libraries.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to process this image so that you can reduce the size but quality you can maintain. You need to run a background task so that during big image process device doesn't fizz.

Then you can show a progress dialog during this process just add this code into your onCreate activity.

```
public ProgressDialog progressDialog;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MyProfileEidtActivity.this);
progressDialog.setMessage("Loading ...");


// just execute this process

new ImageProcessing().execute("YOUR IMAGE PATH");
}


public class ImageProcessing extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    progressDialog.setMessage("Image Processing");
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.show();
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
    Bitmap mainImage = null;
    Bitmap converetdImage = null;
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = null;
    byte[] bt = null;
    String encodeString = null;
    try {
        mainImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(strings[0]);

    /// 500 means image size will be maximum 500 kb

        converetdImage = getResizedBitmap(mainImage, 500);
        bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        converetdImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, bos);
        bt = bos.toByteArray();
        encodeString = Base64.encodeToString(bt, Base64.DEFAULT);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return encodeString;
 }

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String image) {
    super.onPostExecute(s);
    progressDialog.dismiss();

 // this image will be your reduced image path

}
 }

public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap image, int maxSize) {
int width = image.getWidth();
int height = image.getHeight();

float bitmapRatio = (float) width / (float) height;
if (bitmapRatio > 1) {
    width = maxSize;
    height = (int) (width / bitmapRatio);
} else {
    height = maxSize;
    width = (int) (height * bitmapRatio);
}
return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, width, height, true);
}
```